# What does "great good" mean in the tutorial title "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!"?

Tags: meaning

There is a site [learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com) with the title "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!". Does "Great Good" mean "very very good"? Does the whole phrase mean "learning Haskell is good for you" or "learning Haskell is good for the whole world" or something else?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Haskell is a very mathematical programming language. It is typically learned by mathematically inclined people who have big brains. That makes the subject matter frightening to many people. It triggers their "math anxiety".

The title is deliberately silly so as not to make people feel anxious. Haskell books are typically pedantic and formal. The informal, grammatically incorrect, silly style of the title is kind of promise to the reader that the book won't be overly pedantic and formal.

I think also that the author, who is Slovenian, may be making fun of his own English skills. (The English inside the book however is very good.)

In better English, the title might be something like, "Learn Haskell for great benefit".

Comment: There is also a farcical echo, even if subliminal, of [Zero-Wing's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfwqvUPIRkg) "For great justice!" (1:15).

Answer (score 20):

It's a deliberate mistake, as is "Learn You". I think this is based on a comedy routine by Sacha Baron Cohen called Borat.

Answer (score 13):

I'm inclined to think it's a parody of "For great justice!" from the badly-translated game, Zero Wing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us

Answer (score 7):

According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3jm69v/origin_of_learnwrite_yourself_aansome_language/cuqpg3r) the phrasing originated in the title of the [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) tutorial "[Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 hours](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours)", written in 2006, and was simply a (not that ungrammatical, but certainly awkward) "portmanteau of two different common memes at the time": the "Teach yourself X in 21 days books", and Peter Norvig's semi-parody "Teach yourself programming in 10 years".

Comment: Um that user doesn't speak for Miran Lipovača, who himself said, ["yeah I couldn't think of a title so i said ok let's make it something absolutely stupid and i sort of thought haha what if borat wrote a haskell tutorial"](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/es9o3/learn_you_some_erlang_for_great_good_in_epub/c1akrbs/). That is not say there was not an influence, probably, but it is not entirely why.

Comment: @MarkC Isn't that pretty much what that user is saying (if you read the whole post)?

Comment: @MarkC that's the answer!

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a Haskell joke, playing on the functional programming style used in that language.

Comment: Learn:: (you, a Haskell)->Great Good - Learn is a function that takes you and an object a of class Haskell and outputs an object Great Good.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be more inclined to interpret "for Great Good" as a form of "for the Greater Good".

In that case it corresponds with "learning Haskell is good for whole world" per your suggestion.

Compare to "Making the world a better place, one person at a time".

Comment: "For great good" is fine, with good (e.g. toward oneself) being a noun. The only real "quirk" is the intentionally "*a* Haskell" for goofiness. With the transitive "learn", they together exaggerate the effect.

Answer (score -1):

It could mean 'good' in the economic sense, where it is a noun. But somehow I doubt it.